# PLSQL error PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, syntax-error

Error:

```
ORA-06550: linha 13, coluna 26:
    PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo ";" quando era esperado um dos seguintes:
     . ( @ % not null range index
```

Code:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rec IS RECORD(
    cod_unidade    ide_controle%TYPE,
    num_sequencial ide_taxas.num_sequencial%TYPE,
    num_taxa       ide_taxas%TYPE,
    quant          NUMBER,
    modulo         VARCHAR2,
    episodio       con_registadas.con_episodio%TYPE,
    dta_realizacao con_registadas.dta_realizacao%TYPE,
    des_adm        VARCHAR2,
    valor          ide_taxas.valor_actor%TYPE);

TYPE col IS TABLE OF rec;   <-----ERROR???
    lines col;
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: It should be `VARCHAR2(some number)`

Comment: That's true, but it should be getting PLS-00215 against line 7 and line 10 for that. Where is the PLS-00103 coming from? Have any of the names been changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
  -- Local variables here
    TYPE rec IS RECORD(
    cod_unidade    ide_controle%TYPE,
    num_sequencial ide_taxas.num_sequencial%TYPE,
    num_taxa       ide_taxas%TYPE,
    quant          NUMBER,
    modulo         VARCHAR2(100),----------------------
    episodio       con_registadas.con_episodio%TYPE,
    dta_realizacao con_registadas.dta_realizacao%TYPE,
    des_adm        VARCHAR2(100),----------------------
    valor          ide_taxas.valor_actor%TYPE);

TYPE col IS TABLE OF rec; 
...
```